# Qt4 How to draw inside a widget?

Tags: qt, graphics, qt4, qt-creator

Qt4, QtCreator

I am trying to draw inside Widget:

```
void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QPainter painter;

    painter.begin(ui->label);

    QRectF rectangle(10.0, 20.0, 80.0, 60.0);
     int startAngle = 30 * 16;
     int spanAngle = 120 * 16;
     painter.drawArc(rectangle, startAngle, spanAngle);

    painter.end();
}
```

But when I press button nothing happens.

How to do this right way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to override [paintEvent()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent) and do your painting there. You don't really need the `begin()` and `end()`. Declare the painter with

```
QPainter painter(this);
```

The constructor will handle `begin()`, and `end()` will be called when the `painter` object goes out of scope and is destroyed.

You also won't need the click event to trigger the painting. `paintEvent()` will be called whenever the widget needs to draw itself. You could use the the button click to toggle a boolean that the `paintEvent()` checks to determine whether or not it should display the rectangle and arc. Just make sure you call `update()` after you toggle the variable.

```
void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    drawShapes = !drawShapes;
    update();
}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    if(drawShapes)
    {
        QRectF rectangle(10.0, 20.0, 80.0, 60.0);
        int startAngle = 30 * 16;
        int spanAngle = 120 * 16;
        painter.drawArc(rectangle, startAngle, spanAngle);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To avoid having to override the `paintEvent()` of a widget, you could use a `QLabel` and assign a pixmap to it and paint to that. Note: As far as I can tell, you will need to set the pixmap each time you modify it.

```
void MainForm::slot_buttonClick()
{
    QPixmap pixmap(100,100);
    pixmap.fill(QColor("transparent"));

    QPainter painter(&pixmap);
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::black));
    painter.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

    label.setPixmap(pixmap);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to paint without overriding? Or is there any component on which i can draw without any event, like TImage or TForm or any other component containing TCanvas in VCL(Delphi)? (In Delphi could just write Form1.Canvas.Circle(...) whenever i need it, not only inside onpaint event)

Comment: I've never actually tried drawing on a widget with code external to the widget but QWidget does inherit PaintDevice so it should be possible.

Comment: Scratch that, from the docs for QPainter.. "Warning: When the paintdevice is a widget, QPainter can only be used inside a paintEvent() function or in a function called by paintEvent(); that is unless the Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent widget attribute is set. On Mac OS X and Windows, you can only paint in a paintEvent() function regardless of this attribute's setting."

Comment: You could use a QLabel and QPixmap, draw on the pixmap and assign it to the label. I added an update with code above.

Answer (score 1):

If you overwrite the paint-method as described by Arnold Spence, you should call the parent's paintEvent or you end up with a widget that only shows your rectangle on a white background.